# Have Gulp-concat merge only relevant data

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

The basic usage case for `concat` is straight-forward:

```
gulp.task('generate-manifest', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*/data.json')
    .pipe(concat('manifest.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(./path/to/dest));
});
```

However `data.json` contains some data not relevant for the `manifest.json`, so I want to add an extra step to pull only the relevant pieces of json I need from each `data.json`, and add that json to the manifest.

I was hoping that I could something like:

```
gulp.task('generate-manifest', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*/data.json')
    .pipe(myCustomFunction())
    .pipe(concat('manifest.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(./path/to/dest));
});
```

Where `myCustomFunction()` takes `data.json` and returns only the relevant data. What I am unclear about is how to pass through the `data.json` object|path to `myCustomFunction()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much what [`gulp-json-editor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-editor) was made for (the [usage example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-json-editor#usage) even demonstrates it on a `manifest.json` file).

All you have to do is pass your custom function to `jeditor()`. Your custom function is called for each `data.json` file and you can return a modified JSON object that contains only the relevant data:

```
var jeditor = require("gulp-json-editor");

gulp.task('generate-manifest', function () {
  return gulp.src('./*/data.json')
    .pipe(jeditor(function(json) {
      delete json.unwantedData;
      return json;
    }))
    .pipe(concat('manifest.json'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./path/to/dest'));
});
```

(BTW: I'm pretty sure you can't just concat a bunch of JSON objects and get a valid JSON object out of that.)

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks!